# How to get the value from another table under same DB in LARAVEL?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to ask how to call the value from another table under same database ?

Database table name: `bit_app_policy_category`

Under the database I have these columns:

1. ID
2. code
3. description
4. parent_id
5. status

Another Database Table name under same database : `company_policy`
Under the database i have these columns:

1. ID
2. policy_category_id
3. policy_title
4. version_no
5. policy_details
6. expiry_date
7. file_path

As for now I want to link the table `bit_app_policy_category` and get the columns of id's value into `company_policy` - `policy_category_id`. I don't know how to write the code.

Here is my current code :

```
        <form method="post" action="{{route('policy.store')}}">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            @csrf




            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bit_app_policy_category_parent">Parent Category</label>
                <select id="bit_app_policy_category_parent"  name="parent_id" class="form-control">
                    <option value=" {{"$parents->id"}} </option>n>

                </select>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="company_policy_policy_title">Policy Title<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="company_policy_policy_title" type="text" name="policy_title" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter the policy title" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="company_policy_version-no">Version-no<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="company_policy_version-no" type="text" name="version_no" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter the Version-no" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="company_policy_policy_details">Policy Details<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="company_policy_policy_details" type="text" name="policy_details" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter the Policy Details" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="company_policy_expiry_date">Expiry Date<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="company_policy_expiry_date" type="datetime-local" name="expiry_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter the Expiry Date time" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="company_policy_file_path">Policy File Path<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="company_policy_file_path" type="text" name="file_path" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter the file path" />
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit"  class="btn btn btn-primary"  />
                <a href="{{url('/policy')}}" ><span class="mj btn btn btn-danger">Back</span></a>
                <a href="{{url('/')}}" ><span class="mj btn btn btn-danger">Back to home</span></a>


            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

Comment: Are these two tables in same database?

Comment: @Rob yes , under same database but different tables

Comment: What is common between these two tables like `id`?

Comment: @WONG KIING ANG BCN16090004 you can use relationship like one to many or one to one

Comment: For the id columns under the (bit_app_policy_category) it's unique, for the (policy_category_id ) columns under the ( company_policy) table is just calling the value out from the table ( bit_app_policy_category) id columns value... all i want to do is call out the Id value from the ( bit_app_policy_category ) id columns and link the value to the ( policy_category_id)

Comment: @TanvirAhmed im totally new to lavarel , and i don't really know how to do the code , can u guide me more ?

Comment: do you have already made model for that ?

Comment: okay so you want to get the all  bit_app_policy_category with company policy attached to it ?

Comment: Please can you edit your question and copy and paste the code for the models?

Comment: @Qonvex620 Yes , i just want to get the ( id value from ) - ( bit_app_category) and put inside to the ( id column ) under the ( company_policy ) table

Comment: but the data for company policy you already get it ?

Answer (score 0):

First create two model
 1. **PolicyCategory** and put the code in model

```
public function companyPolicies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CompanyPolicy');
    }
```

**2.CompanyPolicy**

```
  public function policyCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PolicyCategory',policy_category_id);
}
```

and in you controller then you can get all the info of related table. Like say, you have one/two company under the policy_category which id is 1. Now you can get all the companies info like below

```
$policy_category  = PolicyCategory::find(1);
dd($policy_category->companyPolicies);
```

try this and let me know is this really you want or not

Comment: not working, actually i have the model already, i just want to call the value out from the first table into the second table id column

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851964/how-to-get-the-value-from-another-table-under-same-database-in-laravel