# How to get the value from another table under same database in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Make it simple... i have 1 database with 2 table which name `( bit_app_policy_category)` and `(company_policy)`.
Inside `(bit_app_policy_category)` i have these columns:

```
1. id
2. code
3. description
4. parent_id
5. status
```

Inside `( company_policy )` i have these columns:

```
1. id
2. policy_category_id
3. policy_title
4. version_no
5. policy_details
6. expiry_date
```

so what i want is to get the data value from the column `( 1.id )` inside the `( bit_app_policy_category )` into `( company_policy )` `(2.policy_category_id)` column, but i don't know how to do it, i have been finding solution for like 20+ hrs and still lost and so done... could someone help me out ?

```
  <input  type="hidden"
                    name="policy_category_id"
                    value="{{ $id ?? ''}}"
            />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="company_policy(policy_category_id)">Policy Category ID</label>
                <select id="bit_app_policy_category_id"  name="id" class="form-control">
                    <option value="{{null}}">--Select Category--</option>


                </select>
            </div>
```

i want the data value import into the option value which under the code line at --Select Category--

categoryController

```
class categoryController extends Controller
```

{

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $codeSearch = $request->get('code');
    $descriptionSearch = $request->get('description');
    // //This line code is for sorting in ascending order or descending order
    $field = $request->get('field') != '' ? $request->get('field') : 'id';
    //This line code is for sorting in ascending order or descending order
    $sort = $request->get('sort')!=''? $request->get('sort'):'asc';



    $categories = Category::where('code', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')
        ->where('description', 'like', '%' . $descriptionSearch . '%')
        ->orderBy($field, $sort)
        ->paginate(6)
        ->withPath('?search=' . $codeSearch . '&description=' . $descriptionSearch . '&field=' . $field . '&sort=' . $sort);


    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($policy = Category::find($category->parent_id, 'description')) {
            $category->parent_id = $policy->description;
        }
    }

    return view('category.index', ['category' => $categories]);
}


public function create()
{
    $parents = Category::all();//DB::table("bit_app_policy_category")->lists("name","id");
    //Category::all();
    return view('category.create', compact('parents'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [

        'code' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required',
    ]);


    $category = new Category([
        'id' => $request->get('id'),
        'code' => $request->get('code'),
        'description' => $request->get('description'),
        'parent_id' => $request->get('parent_id'),
        'status' => $request->get('status'),
    ]);

    try {
        $category->save();
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
        if($errorCode == '1062'){
            $status1 = 'failed';
            $statusMsg1 = 'Failed to Create, Duplication Code '.$request->get('code').'!';
            return redirect()->back()->with($status1, $statusMsg1);
        }

    }
    $category->save();
    return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('success', 'Data has been successfully added into the system');
}



public function show($id)
{
    //
}


public function edit($id)
{

    $category = Category::find($id);

    $parents = Category::all();
    $parents=DB::table('bit_app_policy_category')->whereNotIn('id',[$id])->get();
    return  view('category.edit')-> with('parents', $parents)-> with('category', $category)->with('id', $id);

}


public function subRequest()
{
    return view('subRequest');
}


public function subRequestPost()
{
    $input = request()->all();
    return response()->json(['success' => 'Got Submit Request.'])->setCallback($this)->input('callback');

}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
    $this->validate($request, [

        'code' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required'
    ]);
    $category = Category::find($id);

    $category->code = $request->get('code');
    $category->description = $request->get('description');
    $category->parent_id = $request->get('parent_id');
    $category->status = $request->get('status');
    $category->save();


    return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('success', 'Data Updated');
}



public function destroy($id)
{

    $status = 'success';
    $statusMsg = 'Data Deleted';



    try {
        $category = Category::find($id);
        $category->delete();
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        if($e->getCode() == "23000") {
            $status = 'failed';
            $statusMsg = 'Failed to Delete! This Record Already Been Referred!';

            return redirect()->back()->with($status, $statusMsg);
        }
        else{
            $status = 'failed';
            $statusMsg = 'Database Error! Please Contact System Administrator!';

            return redirect()->back()->with($status, $statusMsg);
        }
     }
    return redirect()->route('category.index')->with($status, $statusMsg);

}
```

}

For the policyController

class policyController extends Controller
{

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $codeSearch = $request->get('policy_category_id');
    $descriptionSearch = $request->get('policy_title');
    // //This line code is for sorting in ascending order or descending order
    $field = $request->get('field') != '' ? $request->get('field') : 'id';
    //This line code is for sorting in ascending order or descending order
    $sort = $request->get('sort')!=''? $request->get('sort'):'asc';


    //This line code is for searching description on the index page//
    $policy = Policy::where('policy_category_id', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')
        ->where('policy_title', 'like', '%' . $descriptionSearch . '%')
        ->orderBy($field, $sort)
        ->paginate(6)
        ->withPath('?search=' . $codeSearch . '&description=' . $descriptionSearch . '&field=' . $field . '&sort=' . $sort);


    return view('policy.index', ['policy' => $policy]);

}






public function create()
{
    $parents = Policy::all();//DB::table("company_policy")->lists("name","id");
    //Policy::all();
    return view('policy.create', compact('parents'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [


        'policy_category_id' => 'required',
        'policy_title' => 'required',
        'version_no' => 'required',
        'policy_details' => 'required',
        'expiry_date' => 'required',
        'file_path' => 'required',

    ]);


    $policy = new Policy([
        'id' => $request->get('id'),
        'policy_category_id' => $request->get('policy_category_id'),
        'policy_title' => $request->get('policy_title'),
        'version_no' => $request->get('version_no'),
        'policy_details' => $request->get('policy_details'),
        'expiry_date' => $request->get('expiry_date'),
        'file_path' => $request->get('file_path'),
        'created_by'=> Auth::id(),
        'modified_by'=> Auth::id(),

    ]);



    try {
        $policy->save();
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
        if ($errorCode == '1062') {
            $status1 = 'failed';
            $statusMsg1 = 'Failed to Create, Duplication Code ' . $request->get('code') . '!';
            return redirect()->back()->with($status1, $statusMsg1);
        }

    }
    $policy->save();
    return redirect()->route('policy.index')->with('success', 'Data has been successfully added into the system');
}


public function show($id)
{
    //
}


public function edit($id)
{
```

//
        $policy = Policy::find($id);

```
    $parents = Policy::all();
    $parents=DB::table('company_policy')->whereNotIn('id',[$id])->get();
    return  view('policy.edit')-> with('parents', $parents)-> with('policy', $policy)->with('id', $id);

}

public function subRequest()
{
    return view('subRequest');
}



public function subRequestPost()
{
    $input = request()->all();
    return response()->json(['success' => 'Got Submit Request.'])->setCallback($this)->input('callback');

}


public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [

        'policy_category_id' => 'required',
        'policy_title' => 'required',
        'version_no' => 'required',
        'policy_details' => 'required',
        'expiry_date' => 'required',
    ]);
    $policy = Policy::find($id);

    $policy->policy_category_id = $request->get('policy_category_id');
    $policy->policy_title = $request->get('policy_title');
    $policy->version_no = $request->get('version_no');
    $policy->policy_details = $request->get('policy_details');
    $policy->expiry_date = $request->get('expiry_date');
    $policy->save();


    return redirect()->route('policy.index')->with('success', 'Data Updated');
}


public function destroy($id)
{

    $status = 'success';
    $statusMsg = 'Data Deleted';



    try {
        $policy = Policy::find($id);
        $policy->delete();
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        if($e->getCode() == "23000") {
            $status = 'failed';
            $statusMsg = 'Failed to Delete! This Record Already Been Referred!';

            return redirect()->back()->with($status, $statusMsg);
        }
        else{
            $status = 'failed';
            $statusMsg = 'Database Error! Please Contact System Administrator!';

            return redirect()->back()->with($status, $statusMsg);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->route('policy.index')->with($status, $statusMsg);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please see syntax

```
$results = CompanyPolicy::leftJoin('bit_app_policy_category', 'company_policy.id', 'bit_app_policy_category.policy_category_id')->get();
```

where CompanyPolicy is model for company_policy and please change your keys accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**use ajax.first of all get all categories from bit_app_policy_category table inside your method which you are using to show this view**

```
      //controller 
        if you did not create any model create model first
        function function_name(){
        $categories=\App\BitAppPolicyCategory:get();
        return view('blade_file_name', compact('categories'));
        }

    //in blade file
    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="company_policy(policy_category_id)">Policy Category ID</label>
                    <select id="bit_app_policy_category_id"  name="id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" >--Select Category--</option>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
                     <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->code}}</option>
          @endforeach

                    </select>
                </div>

   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="company_policy)">Policy Category ID</label>
                    <select id="company_policy"  name="company_policy" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" >--Select Policy--</option>
      </select>
                </div>
//ajax
$("#bit_app_policy_category_id").on('change', function () {
    get_company_policy($(this).val())
});
function get_company_policy(industry_type) {
    fetch(base_url + '/get_compny_policy_by_bit_policy_category_id/' + bit_app_policy_category_id)
            .then(function (response) {
                var html = '<option value="" selected="selected">Select Type</option>';
                response.json().then(function (res) {
                    if (res.length > 0) {
                        $.each(res, function (i, v) {
                            html += '<option ' + (company_policy == v.id ? 'selected="selected"' : '') + ' value="' + v.id + '">' + v.policy_title + '</option>';
                        });
                        $("#company_policy").html(html);
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(function () {
                alert('no data')
            });
}
```